# Mayúsculas en apellidos con preposiciones

Tags: preposiciones, uso-de-mayúsculas

Siempre he tenido una confusion con los apellidos con preposiciones, tales como: "de los Santos, de la Rosa, del Carmen".

Mi pregunta es si estos se deben escribir como se indica arriba o si las preposiciones deben ir en mayúscula, "De Los Santos", por ejemplo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

En la [Ortografía de la lengua española](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=QeajYwPZtRcoxZgg) se explica cuándo se usa mayúscula y cuándo no para apellidos con preposiciones:

> Si un apellido comienza por preposición, o por preposición y artículo, estos se escriben con minúscula cuando acompañan al nombre de pila: *Luis de Torres, Juana de la Rosa*; pero, si se omite el nombre de pila, la preposición debe escribirse con mayúscula: *señor De Torres, De la Rosa*.